# Problem converting from standard django form select to select2

Tags: django, jquery-select2

I am trying to convert django form from using standard select to select2. I have followed instruction and installed django-select-forms, added select2 to INSTALLED_APPS, and include select2 links and scripts in the header block

Here is my original code

Model.py

```py
    class Photographer(models.Model):
        author_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
        displayname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

forms.py

```py
    class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(UploadFileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['author'].required = True
            self.fields['author'].queryset = 
    Photographer.objects.all().order_by('displayname')
```

Is ther anyway I can do this without changing my model?

Comment: What problem do you encounter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you only will need to specify the widget you use:

```
from django_select2.forms import Select2Widget

class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UploadFileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['author'].required = True
        self.fields['author'].queryset = Photographer.objects.order_by('displayname')

    class Meta:
        widgets = {'author': Select2Widget }
```

That being said, since you already are specifying some data in the `__init__`, it might be more elgant to define this as a class attribute instead:

```
from django_select2.forms import Select2Widget

class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    author = ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Photographer.objects.order_by('displayname'),
        required=True,
        widget=Select2Widget
    )
```

Comment: Thank you.  I mad the change accordingly, but there is no change in the rendered form.  I was expecting to see a text box on the dropdown that I can type a  name instead of scrolling down the long list.

Comment: @ChariPete: do you see a difference in the HTML (if you add/remove the widget)? Are you sure the CSS and JS are loading fine in the response (most browsers have an *inspector* for that).

Comment: I did have the js script, but how do I add select id in the form?

Comment: @ChariPete: but you need to include the css as well: https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get_started.html#quick-start

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I missed the css

Comment: I speak too soon.  Im afraid still no change.  The html has changed to ```<select name="author" data-minimum-input-length="0" data-allow-clear="false" class="select2widget form-control django-select2" required id="id_author">```  the id defined in js script is not id_author.

Comment: @ChariPete: and you did include `{{ form.media.js }}` and jQuery?